# Attempting to bind HashMap from MVC model to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Following my recent post: -

[Cascading dropdown from HashMap in Thymeleaf Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568787/cascading-dropdown-from-hashmap-in-thymeleaf-template/58568919#58568919)

I am making steady progress in attempting to get cascading dropdown boxes working in my SpringBoot, Thymeleaf application.

But I am currently struggling in trying to bind a HashMap from my MVC model to a JavaScript variable so that it is then available to the JavaScript code that generates the options for the dropdown boxes. This is what I have tried so far: -

1. In my controller class, I create a HashMap where the key is the category as a String and the value is a list of associated skills, where the Skill class is a Java data object containing the skill name and id: -

   `Map<String, List<Skill>> skillsMap = new HashMap();`
2. On my Thymeleaf template in a script section, I attempt to bind this HashMap to a variable. As a second step I then attempt to retrieve one of the lists from the map and assign to a second variable: -

   `var skillsMapMap = [[${skillsMap}]];`

   `var adminList = skillsMapMap.get('Admin');`
3. When I run the code in developer mode, I can see that the HashMap is being read and an attempt is being made to bind it to my variable. This is the debug line I see: -

   `var skillsMapMap = {Languages=[Python, SQL, PL/SQL, Java], Databases=[MySQL, Oracle, Mongo], Editors=[Word, TextPad, Notepad]};`

This looks good at first glance and contains all my data, but it is throwing the following error: -

```
Uncaught Syntax Error: invalid shorthand property initializer
```

I have searched this error and have found that it is commonly caused by using '=' to assign values rather than ':', and indeed, I can see that each one of entries in my map is assigned using '='.

I would really appreciate any advice on this issue. Perhaps my whole approach is wrong and I shouldn't be attempting to bind a complex model object to a JavaScript variable in this way? Or perhaps I just need to tweak my syntax slightly to get it to work? Many thanks for reading.

EDIT: -

Following the advice from user1538301, I am now attempting to convert my HashMap to a JSON String using the Jackson ObjectMapper before adding to the model: -

```
    String objectMapper = null;
    try {
        // Default constructor, which will construct the default JsonFactory as necessary, use SerializerProvider as its
        // SerializerProvider, and BeanSerializerFactory as its SerializerFactory.
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(skillsMap);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    model.addAttribute("skillsMapJson", objectMapper);
```

When I attempt to bind this to my JavaScript variable, it fails because all the quotes are escaped: -

`var skillsMapJson = {&quot;Languages_OD&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:66,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;SQL&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:67,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;PL/SQL&quot;}], etc, etc};`

This throws the exception: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

I feel this is a step closer and that if the JSON string contained quotes instead of &quot the Map would bind to my variable. Any more advice much appreciated!

Comment: You need to somehow format and convert the HashMap into a string that is valid JavaScript.

Java doesn't serialize a HashMap as valid JavaScript by default, it's just giving you a human-readable output.

Comment: @user1538301 Good advice, thank you. This may achievable by implementing a custom serializer - I'll look into it.